# How to properly configure multi datacenters replica set members for efficient dc crash handling and write ack?

Tags: mongodb

Considering a mongodb replica set  with 5 members  using 3 datacenters.

- DC1 hosts 2 members (R1,R2), a Primary and a secondary
- DC2 hosts 2 members (R3,R4), two secondaries
- DC3 hosts 1 arbiter

I would like to use an approppriate write concern :

- to be able to continue writing data even if  a datacenter is lost
- but also have write done on both datacenters before ack when both DC are up.
  Using the following distribution

Please tell me if I'm wrong with these expectations :

- using w:3 the data will be written to at least one host of DC2, but if any datacenter goes down any write will be blocked indefinitely, waiting for a third replica to goes up. So I can't use w:3.
- using w:majority, considering 'majority' is computed using  replica set members defined in configuration and not the ones up/joignable after a change in the set due to data center down, the write will block, as in previous w:3 case. So I can't use w:majority.
- using w:2, data will be written to primary and replicated on the nearest Secondary, so on the same datacenter.
- using w:eachDC will work when all DC are up, but when one DC goes down the write will be blocked.

How could I configure members and writeconcerns to :

- handle write on both DC before ack to application.
- handle one DC down and still allow write to members
- have a member in each DC with high priority for elections as Primary but also for writeconcern. This way when both DC are up the write will be replicated to this member on remote DC but if this member is elected as new primary after DC goes down It will contain more up2date data than other secondaries on the same DC, and so will limit rollback issues.

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first and second point contradict each other, so you cannot have both.

For a guide on how to set up write concern to require ack from both datacenters, check out [Custom Multidatacenter Write Concerns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/#custom-multi-datacenter-write-concerns), a topic that's part of replica set tags. I think you may have already seen this based on having the write concern "`w:eachDC`", but there it is if you haven't.

If you require ack from both datacenters, how can you expect success when one datacenter is down? You cannot require both DC's to do the write and have the write succeed if one DC can't do the write. You would have to change the write concern. If the write should succeed when one datacenter does it, not necessarily both, you really don't want the write concern you say you want.

Comment: Both situations do not contradict from my point of view, one situation occurs when cluster has it's full integrity (both datacenters up) and the other situation when we are in altered state (one dc down). The Custom Multidatacenter write concerns documentation or the 'Mongodb / the definitive guide' book assume that both datacenters are up when using tag sets. I'm looking for a write concern (or any configuration tips) able to handle write on both datacenters when everything is ok and using the most up2date secondary as primary on the remaining datacenter when other dc goes down.